# CombineLatest in Highland.js

Tags: node.js, rxjs, highland.js

How to achieve a behavior similar to [combineLatest](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) with Highland? It looks like there is nothing similar in the library

Answer (score 1):

My naive implementation is below:

```
 var combineLatest = function(...streams) {
    var _streams = streams.map(
        (s, i) => s.map((x) => {return {[i]: x}})
    )
    return H(_streams).merge().scan1(H.extend).filter((obj) => {
      return Object.keys(obj).length === streams.length
    }).map(obj =>
      _(obj).pairs().reduce(
        (res, [key, val]) => {
          res[key] = val
          return res
        },
        []
      )
    )
  }
combineLatest(users, photos).each((x) => console.log(x))
```

But I have no concerns about performance of such solution